# FOR cmd command to modify files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

What I've got to do is the follow:

_I have multiple text INPUT files ex:

```
   Auditors.txt made like that         Backup users.txt made like taht

   "Auditors"                          "Backup Users",
   "Auditor","3"                       "Backup","1"
   "pippo","20"
```

_the OUTPUT should be:

```
                lista.txt

                Auditors,Auditor,3,pippo,20
                Backup Users,Backup,1
```

I tried to use the following code to achive the result:
(I recall the "FOR" cicle 2 times, one with GRUPPI=auditors.txt and one with GRUPPI=Backup USERS.txt)

```
  ...
  for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ("%GRUPPI%.txt") do(
  echo|set /p=%%a >> lista.txt
  echo|set /p=,   >> lista.txt )
  pause
  ...
```

IT DOESN'T OPEN THE INPUT FILE TO READ THE LINES!
(consider also "Backup Users" have a space that create problems)

RESULTS:
if the FOR argument is set to (%GRUPPI%.txt)   -->  it doesn't even generate the output file lista.txt

if the FOR argument is set to ("%GRUPPI%.txt")   -->  it generate the file lista.txt but in it I just find the input file names!

if I use "usebackq" and ("%GRUPPI%.txt") -->  it doesn't even generate the output file lista.txt

Someone can give me an hint?

Cristian

Answer (score 1):

Read the FOR documenation carefully (`help for` or `for /?`). You will see the USEBACKQ option that changes how the IN() clause is interpreted. The following should get you on your way:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%a in ("%GRUPPI%.txt") do( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
DEL newfile.txt 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21166181.txt) DO (
 SET "gruppi=%%a"  
 CALL :process
)

GOTO :EOF
:process
SET "line="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%c IN ("%gruppi%") DO (
 CALL :build %%c
)
>>newfile.txt ECHO(%line:~1%
GOTO :eof

:build
SET "$1=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED $1 GOTO :EOF
SET "line=%line%,%$1%"
shift
GOTO build
```

If I've got what you want right, this may suit.

`q21166181.txt` contains

```
auditors.txt
backup users.txt
```

`auditors.txt` contains

```
   "Auditors"      
   "Auditor","3"   
   "pippo","20"
```

`backup users.txt` contains

```
  "Backup Users",
     "Backup","1"
```

Result in `newfile.txt` contains

```
Auditors,Auditor,3,pippo,20
Backup Users,Backup,1
```